# Run several scripts in sequence and output each one to a csv file

Tags: sql, ssms, export-to-csv, sqlcmd

I have several queries that need to be run on a weekly basis in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, each one one is just a relatively simple select query, and the results need to be saved into csv file. Right now someone spends an hour running each script in turn and saving the results.

I figured this could be somewhat automated but am struggling.

From reading previous questions here I've gotten as far as using SQLCMD mode, and by putting :output c:\filename.csv I get the output saved into a file, but I am having trouble getting separate files to be generated for each query.

For simplicity's sake, assume my query looks like this:

```
OUT: C:\File1.csv
SELECT * FROM table1;

OUT: C:\File2.csv
SELECT * FROM table2;

OUT: C:\File3.csv
SELECT * FROM table3;
```

Instead of getting three files with the output of each query, I end up with File1 and File2 filled with a couple of unreadable characters, and all three queries in File3. I know in Oracle there is a spool off command, is there something similar for OUT: in SSMS?

Comment: I would still like to know if this could be done within the script itself, but I resorted to the following as a stopgap:    
`for %%G in (*.sql) do sqlcmd /S [server] -U [username] -P "[password] -o "%%G.csv" -s"," -w 700 -i "%%G"`  
`pause`
`for %%A in (*.sql.csv) do for %%B in ("%%~nA") do ren "%%A" "%%~nB.csv"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a somewhat modified query and was able to get three files with three different query results. I ran the following for a quick test:

```
:OUT C:\File1.csv
SELECT 'Hello'

GO

:OUT C:\File2.csv
SELECT 'My'

GO

:OUT C:\File3.csv
SELECT 'Friend'
```

This gave me three separate files with the results from each query in a separate file. All I did was take out the semi colon and added the keyword GO which will terminate a command and move on to the next one. I hope this helps.

Comment: Ahh, thats exactly what I needed, I tried googling all sorts of different terms but somehow never came across anything that said GO essentially ended and started a new script. So I think SQLCMD is possibly slightly more powerful and useful, but this will definitely still be useful for adhoc use, cheers!

Comment: Glad to here that! Happy coding.